# Cascading an association

Tags: symfony

I am trying to [embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), but I am having trouble persisting the newly created objects.

A `Customer` has many `Email`s. In my controller,

```
// CustomersController.php
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->setCreatedBy(0);

$blankEmail = new Email();
$customer->addEmail($blankEmail);

$form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer);
```

I did remember to set the cascade option in my `Customer` class:

```
// Customer.php
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Email", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $emails;
```

My `Email` class also has the required information:

```
// Email.php
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="emails", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customers_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $customer;
```

For some reason, this doesn't work:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();
```

It adds the customer alright, but when it tries to add the Email, it says no customerId has been set. So, I tried this, and it works:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        foreach ($customer->getEmails() as $email) 
            $email->setCustomer($customer);
            $em->persist($email);
        }
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();
```

But I'd really like to be able to get it in one fell swoop, just by persisting the `$customer` object (as I know it can).

Comment: Which `strategy` have you set in the `@GeneratedValue` annotation?

Comment: Both `Customer` and `Email` use "AUTO" for their id. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the default "addEmail" method in your Customer class.

This method should look like:

```
public function addEmail($email)
{
  $email->setCustomer($this);
  $this->emails[] = $email;
  return $this;
}
```